# Getting data from one form into another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have a project that contains two forms, Form1 and Form2. Form1 creates a new instance of Form2. In Form2, I am entering a number for a timer, then in Form1, I want to pull that number, set and start that timer.

However, I am unable to pull that number from Form2 into Form1 during run time. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make it a public property in `Form2` that can be accessed from `Form1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

> DialogResult.

The idea is to open form like this :

```
Form myForm = new Form();
if(myForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Access the value;
    Console.out.WriteLine(myForm.TheValue);
}
```

In myForm you'll have something like that

```
private string sTheValue = null;
public string TheValue
{
    get { return this.sTheValue; }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.sTheValue = "Hello World !";
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var form2 = new Form2(this);
> // OR
> //   var form2 = new Form2();
> //   form2.Form1 = this; // A property created by you, in form1
> form2.ShowDialog();
> ```

Somewhere else in form2

```
this.Form1.No = int.Parse(txt.Text); // No is a property in Form1 which is listening for changes...
```